# Identify all numbers that append '#' in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a message(m) say "fixes #1 ~needs verification".

I want to identify all numbers that append '#'. So, i scan the text:

`issue = m.scan(/[^\#][0-9]+/)`

But `issue` is empty unless the number after # is two digits or > 9 meaning if the message is  "fixes #10 ~needs verification"  then my issue is 10.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're negating the character class, so your regex is matching (anything that isn't #) followed by one or more digits. 2-digit numbers fit this, but one-digit numbers prefixed by # do not.

Here's what you should do instead:

```
issue = m.scan(/#[0-9]+/)
```

Or (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305314/129655)):

```
issue = m.scan(/#\d+/)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"fixes #1 ~needs #12verification" .scan(/#\d+/) #=> ["#1", "#12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the square brackets off of the # sign:

```
issue = m.scan(/^#[0-9]+/)
```